# .htaccess back-references and redirects

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, apache, веб-сервер, apache2

У меня есть URL-адрес `mydomain.com/{number}/C/A/{number}/B`

При использовании регексов и back-referencов не удается получить нужные части строки:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dom5.mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([0-9]+)([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)([0-9]+)\/([A-Za-z]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain1.fun/$5$2/$3 [R=301,L]
```

При некоторых вариантах регекспа получаю `([A-Za-z]+)-([A-Za-z]+)` вот эти части для некоторых $.

Comment: Что-то не видно в регулярках бэкреференсов...

Comment: Да, именно, что не видно. Не понимал, почему [0-9]+ такая штука не работала. Можете  пояснить вкратце?

Comment: _«[0-9]+ такая штука не работала»_ - `[0-9]` это абсолютно то же самое что `\d`, работают они одинаково (`\d` просто короче). Откуда взялся такой странный вывод что штука не работала?

Comment: Вывод $1 был пустой. Выводило только $2 и $3 части строки "{number}{C}-{A}{number}". Возможно нужно было реально % юзать, а в RewriteRule закинуть ^.

Comment: А, почему вывод был пустой - я не разбирался: посмотрел на регулярки в вопросе, подумал "нееее", и просто написал свои. Вообще я не очень разбираюсь в апаче, но предполагаю что пустой вывод мог быть из-за [особенностей директивы `RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), например из-за такой что входной строкой этой директиве передается _относительный к расположению конфига_ путь к документу (тогда как `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` получает на вход путь относительный к document root'у, то есть весь путь к документу начиная от `https://hostname`).

Comment: \*весь путь к документу начиная от `https://hostname{отсюда}`... ну, думаю что понятно о чем речь - о полном относительном пути к документу (относительно схемы с хостнеймом), против частичного относительного пути (относительно директории где лежит `.htaccess`). Конечно, это только предположение, т.к. у `RewriteRule` есть и другие нюансы (см. ссылку выше)... но это по-моему самая вероятная причина нерабочести регулярок в вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dom5.mydomain.fun$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\d+([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)\d+\/([a-z]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mydomain1.fun/%3%1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dom6.mydomain.fun$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mydomain2.fun/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dom7.mydomain.fun$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\d+([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)\d+\/([a-z]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mydomain3.fun/%3%2%1 [R=301,L]
```